# jQuery tablesorter from Json array

Tags: jquery, json

I am working on a search page in MVC, ASP.NET. The user selects from the many search options and the controller returns a Json result. This contains all the required info and these are displayed in a different table.

I've applied the tablesorter after the table is created:

```
function populateTable(data, status) {
          console.log(data);
          $("#SearchResultTable tbody tr").remove();
          for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
               addTableRow(data[i]);
          }

          $("#SearchResultTable").tablesorter({
               sortList: [[0,0]]
          });
}
```

When returning the search results the sorting is done properly, but: 
1: the paging options not working
 2: if I click on any of the sorting arrows in the header, the sorting is done, but "No data available in table" inserted before the first row. 
Any idea what can be the problem?
Thanks in advance for your help.